# Move file that is in use

Tags: c#

I have this problem: I process a file and after I need to move into another folder:
actually I do this:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(BW_FullPathPhoto);
file.MoveTo(sFolderCopy + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(BW_FullPathPhoto));
```

but sometimes give me the error that the file is current in use and is not able to move...

I know that if I rename a file that is in use, windows let me do this... it's possible rename a file without moving (I think that a move performs a copy and after a deletion)

Comment: You cannot move a file that is in use.

Comment: Perhaps a workaround is to copy it and move it and log the ones that have raised an exception to delete after? I guess problem here is you could potentially delete a file that has been modified. Maybe log the ones that have thrown an exception and move them later.

Comment: but I can rename a file that is in use...

Comment: Are you sure you can rename a file that's in use? I highly doubt that's possible. I tried it just to make sure with an Excel file and it doesn't let me rename it "The action can't be completed because the file is open in Microsoft Excel".

Comment: with an exe is possible

Comment: Renaming and moving are completely different things.  There is no reason to think that being able to do one while a file is open means that you should be able to do the other.

Comment: You might want to look at `Path.Combine` too...

Comment: @juharr in Win32, moving and renaming are the same thing. You use the API function `MoveFile` for both (or `MoveFileEx`, or `MoveFileTransacted`)

Comment: @ghiboz you can only rename exe's and dll's because they are memory-mapped by Windows so when you rename them, it'll just change the handle on memory for them to the renamed file (you can rename it but not delete it). The file itself is not "in use" (other than by Windows, which handles the case). If you open the exe file for writing in your application and lock it, it won't let you rename it.

Comment: Is the file in question one that you've made or modified in your application?  If so, make sure you've disposed of all the streams, readers, writers, etc. that reference it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Pathy
{
  internal enum MoveFileFlags
  {
    MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING = 0x1
    , MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED = 0x02
    , MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x04
    , MOVEFILE_CREATE_HARDLINK = 0x10
    , MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH = 0x8
    , MOVEFILE_FAIL_IF_NOT_TRACKABLE = 0x20
  }
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "MoveFileEx")]
  internal static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, MoveFileFlags dwFlags);

  public bool MoveOrReboot(FileInfo fi, DirectoryInfo di)
  {
    fi?.Refresh();
    if (!(di?.Exists ?? false)) throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(di.FullName);
    if (fi?.Exists ?? false)
    {
      try
      {
        fi.MoveTo(di.FullName + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fi.Name);
        return true;
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        switch (e.HResult)
        {
          case -2147024864:  //equivalent 'file in use' error
            if (MoveFileEx(fi.FullName, di.FullName + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fi.Name, MoveFileFlags.MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT))
            {
              return false;
            }
            break;

          default:
            throw e;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        throw e;
      }
    }
    else throw new FileNotFoundException(fi.FullName);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Placed the function into a class and added a return value to gate whether the OS needs to be rebooted or not.

Usage:

```
try
{
  if (!Pathy.MoveOrReboot(fi,di)) reboot_needed = true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  //...
}
```